# Any idea why i dont have gutters between my articles ? Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm Struggling adjusting my articles here  :

https://cryptoranger.net/news

I'm using bootstrap 4.3.0, here's the code of the rows :

```
<div class="row bg-light"> 
    <?php
    foreach ($newsList as $news){?>
    <article class="col-md-4 blogpost border rounded p-0">
            <div class="imgBx">
                <img src="/images/<?=$news['image'] ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="itemrecent1"><?= $news['titre'] ?></h2>
              <p class="float-left m-0"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>  <?= $news['dateAjout']->format('Y-m-d') ?></p><br>
              <p class="itemrecent1"><?= nl2br($news['contenu']) ?></p>
                <?php
                if ($category === 'news'){?>
              <div class="itemrecent1"><a href="/news/<?php echo $generator->generate($news['titre']); ?>_<?= $news['id'] ?>" class="btn btnD1">Read</a></div>
                <?php
                }else {?>
              <div class="itemrecent1 justify-self-end"><a href="/guide/<?= $category ?>/<?php echo $generator->generate($news['titre']); ?>_<?= $news['id'] ?>" class="btn btnD1">Read</a></div>
                <?php
                }?>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
    </article>
    <?php } ?>   <!-- End of news -->
</div>
```

So i want gutters between my articles...

Besides, if you know how to adjust the content (text inside the box because i tried some flexbox css but nothing is changing (i want at least all Read link at the same level (bottom))...

==> It's working if i put some height in pixel but cant do that because i need responsive design..

Thanks... :D

Comment: `p-0` removes the padding which creates the gutter

Comment: hey, already did it but look the result ..

Comment: same problem without p-0 i got a padding but still no spaces between my articles

Answer (score 1):

The gutters are there, they come from the padding on the `col-*` classes.  Because you added the `border` class to your articles the padding is, naturally, surrounded by a border.  Usually when using Bootstrap grid layouts, content is placed within a wrapper element that has the desired `col-*` class:

```
<div class="row bg-light"> 
    <?php
    foreach ($newsList as $news){?>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <article class="blogpost border rounded p-0">
            <div class="imgBx">
                <img src="/images/<?=$news['image'] ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2 class="itemrecent1"><?= $news['titre'] ?></h2>
              <p class="float-left m-0"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>  <?= $news['dateAjout']->format('Y-m-d') ?></p><br>
              <p class="itemrecent1"><?= nl2br($news['contenu']) ?></p>
                <?php
                if ($category === 'news'){?>
              <div class="itemrecent1"><a href="/news/<?php echo $generator->generate($news['titre']); ?>_<?= $news['id'] ?>" class="btn btnD1">Read</a></div>
                <?php
                }else {?>
              <div class="itemrecent1 justify-self-end"><a href="/guide/<?= $category ?>/<?php echo $generator->generate($news['titre']); ?>_<?= $news['id'] ?>" class="btn btnD1">Read</a></div>
                <?php
                }?>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
    </article>
  </div>
    <?php } ?>   <!-- End of news -->
</div>
```

Looks like you actually have it correct on [another page on your site](https://cryptoranger.net/#guides)